# Trying to make a float change using CSS and Media Query

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make an image float on the left for all media queries above a mobile in landscape and portrait and for mobile and below then the image goes full display block, i.e. center position.

In summary:

**Mobile or below** (min-device-width : 320px) = image to be full block (center)

**Higher than 320px** = image to float left.

I can't get it to work though....

Here's my CSS:

```
.img-float {
  float:left;margin:0 20px 20px 0;
  }

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
  .img-float {
   display:block;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
 }
}
```

Here's the markup:

```
<p>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/175x80/000/fff" class="img-float">

    FutureCon put on a great show and they&#8217;re touring the US at the moment with over a dozen different IT Security Events throughout the United States. These events are particularly good for networking and advancing your career.
</p>
```

Am I doing it wrong with using a class for the image?

Not sure how to make this work.

Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the image wasn't floating then the `display` and `margin` would centre it.

… but it **is** floating.

You need to stop it floating as well:

```
float: none
```

Comment: I added that and no joy - the image remains left-aligned (left-float) even when the screen solution is reduced to the mobile query.

Comment: Since I can't be bothered to find a device which meets the physical constraints in your media query, I tweaked it to use a simple max-width and then tested it in my desktop browser. It worked fine when I added `float: none`.

Comment: Yes, I got it working - @media (min-width: 768px) worked well. Thanks for your help!